# DataGridView with LINQ fast autosave changes

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm use DataGridView with LINQ BindingSource. And I need autosave changes after adding, editing or deleting rows by:

dataContext.SubmitChanges();

Now I'm use AddedRow, DeletedRow, ValueChanged events, but when user delete 1000 rows, this causes 1000 calls of "dataContext.SubmitChanges();" and this is very slow.

How i can call "dataContext.SubmitChanges();" one time after adding, deleting or editing all rows?

Comment: Is there any event like DataChanged you could use instead of AddedRow, DeletedRow and so on?

Comment: As a usability note, you may want to think of adding a prompt/message box when a user does deletes. This way you can confirm they wanted to delete those rows and it wasn't a 'fat finger' incident.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the List_Changed event of your bindingSource, like explained here:
[aving busniess object using a bindingsource](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/9366bbe0-be79-40dc-a67f-747bdd23ecb4/)